# how to fetch previous search result?

Tags: angular

I have search button. When result appear, I open one of the result then when I click on back button, the search result disappear.

I already tried to get the value based on search.

```
clientFilter(event) {
const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
// filter our data
const temp = this.temp.filter(function(d) {
  return d.clientName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
});
// update the rows
this.rows = temp;
this.table.offset = 0;
}
```

I want the value what I searched before should appear.

Comment: So it's really not quite clear what you want, and what your doing. What do you mean by `open`? navigate to it? And I don't understand what you mean by `I already tried to get the value based on search`. You could post (**only the snippets so that your problem occurs, not your full code!!**) on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) and share the link. In that way I could take a look at your problem "working" (well more likely not working :D) in action :)

Comment: 1) when I search the keyword for example "xyz". It will show the result start from "xyz". 2) When I click on that result "xyz", it will open new page related to "xyz" details. 3) When I click on BACK button, my search result "xyz", disappear. 4) I want that search result back when I click on back button.

Comment: I'm guessing you are navigating with the router?

Answer (score 0):

**This might seem like a lot to take in but it's really easy when you get the hang of it. At the bottom I included a somewhat working example, where you can search and then click on the `go to more info` link and navigate back to find your search query still present.**

So I'm guessing you are using the angular router.

In this case I'd suggest using an url parameter. This would look something like that inside your `routing.module.ts`:

```
{path: 'yourComponent/:search', component: YourComponent },
{path: 'yourComponent', component: YourComponent },
```

After that you can get the url parameter in this manner (I put it in the ngOnInit function):

```
ngOnInit() {
  // Extract search parameter
  this.searchTerm = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('search');
}
```

And assign it to a variable so we can use it for the inputs value which in this case looks like:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." [value]="searchTerm" (keydown)="searchFor($event.target.value)" >
```

As you can see there is a keydown event listener. In a real application I would pass it through a subject for debouncing (learn more about it [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1) but don't worry about it if your not interested).

My `searchFor` function then looks like this:

```
public searchFor(term: string): void {
  // Update the search term
  this.searchTerm = term;
  // Replace the current url
  this.location.replaceState(`home/${term}`); 

  // Do some filtering and displaying that list
```

}

Now If you navigate away from the component, you can simply press the back button, it will navigate back to your url and this line (that I already showed you earlier):

```
this.searchTerm = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('search');
```

Will set the passed value.

This also has the pleasant side effect that you can share your link while searching and the receiver that opens the link will get exactly the same result!

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ciy5pz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent-one%2Fcomponent-one.component.ts)